# Matching data from multiple columns in r

Tags: r, match, subset, lookup

I have two datasets:

Contacts2: This contains a list of ~100,000 contacts, their respective titles and a set of columns which describes the types of work contacts could be involved in. Here's an example dataset:

```
First<-c("George","Thomas","James","Jimmy","Howard","Herbert")
Last<-c("Washington", "Jefferson", "Madison", "Carter", "Taft", "Hoover")
Title<-c("CEO", "Accountant","Communications Specialist", "President", "Accountant", "CFO")
Finance<-NA
Executive<-NA
Communications<-NA

Contacts2<-as.data.frame(cbind(First,Last,Title,Finance,Executive,Communications))

    First       Last                     Title Finance Executive Communications
1  George Washington                       CEO    <NA>      <NA>           <NA>
2  Thomas  Jefferson                Accountant    <NA>      <NA>           <NA>
3   James    Madison Communications Specialist    <NA>      <NA>           <NA>
4   Jimmy     Carter                 President    <NA>      <NA>           <NA>
5  Howard       Taft                Accountant    <NA>      <NA>           <NA>
6 Herbert     Hoover                       CFO    <NA>      <NA>           <NA>
```

Note the last three columns are numeric.

TableOfTitle: This dataset contains a list of ~1,000 unique titles and the same set of columns in which describes the type of work the contacts could be involved in. For each title I've put an 1 in the column(s) of the roles that describe that person's job.

```
Title<-c("CEO","Accountant", "Communications Specialist", "President", "CFO")
Finance<-c(NA,1,NA,1,1)
Executive<-c(1,NA,NA,NA,1)
Communications<-c(NA,NA,1,NA,NA)
TableOfTitle<-as.data.frame(cbind(Title,Finance,Executive,Communications))

                      Title Finance Executive Communications
1                       CEO    <NA>         1           <NA>
2                Accountant       1      <NA>           <NA>
3 Communications Specialist    <NA>      <NA>              1
4                 President       1      <NA>           <NA>
5                       CFO       1         1           <NA>
```

Note the last three columns are numeric.

I'm now trying to match the check boxes in `TableOfTitle` in `Contacts2` based on the contact title field. For example, since `TableOfTitle` shows anyone with the title of CFO should have an x in the Finance and Executive field, the record for Herbert Hoover in `Contacts2` should also have 1s in those columns as well.

Comment: Why not `merge` the two sets?

Comment: Just perform a left join with `merge(Contacts2, TableOfTitle, by = "Title", all.x = TRUE)`

Comment: And you don't need the Finance, Executive, and Communications columns in the first table, because those will be added in the join.

Comment: That could be an option however, what I'm trying to do is a little more complicated. In my actual dataset I have some values already in the last three columns of Contacts2. I would eventually write a rule that says if a value already exists, do not replace.

Comment: Then rename columns in second dataset  prior to merge and then run your `ifelse` logic.

Comment: You actually don't even need to rename them since R will automatically add a `.x` or `.y` suffix to indicate the source table, but it may be helpful for clarity in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that uses `dplyr`. It is essentially what some commenters have already recommended, except that this fulfills the request of not copying over any pre-existing data in the last 3 columns of `Contacts2`.

Note that `ifelse()` can be very slow with large datasets, but for your stated task this shouldn't really be noticeable. Algorithmically, this solution is also a bit clumsy in other ways, but I went for maximum readability here.

```
Contacts2 <- left_join(Contacts2, TableOfTitle, by = "Title") %>%
             transmute(First = First,
                       Last = Last,
                       Title = Title,
                       Finance = ifelse(is.na(Finance.x), Finance.y, Finance.x),
                       Executive = ifelse(is.na(Executive.x), Executive.y, Executive.x),
                       Communications = ifelse(is.na(Communications.x), Communications.y, Communications.x))
```

Example output:

```
First        Last                     Title Finance Executive Communications
George Washington                       CEO    <NA>        1           <NA>
Thomas  Jefferson                Accountant      1       <NA>          <NA>
James     Madison Communications Specialist    <NA>      <NA>            1
Jimmy      Carter                 President      1       <NA>          <NA>
Howard       Taft                Accountant      1       <NA>          <NA>
Herbert    Hoover                       CFO      1         1           <NA>
```